# Length of hypotenuse using one side length and angle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I bet this question has been asked a million times, but I can't find a straight answer. I need to find the length of the hypotenuse in a triangle where I have one side and all the angles.

Example:

[image: Triangle with one side and three angles]

Now in the above triangle I have the length of `a = 20` and all the angles. How do I - from here - get the length of the hypotenuse (`c`)?

Comment: according to the formula $c\cdot\cos 30 = a$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use Law of sines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): it states that

$$\frac{a}{\sin{\alpha}} = \frac{b}{\sin{\beta}} = \frac{c}{\sin{\gamma}}$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the angles opposited to sides $a, b, c$ respectively. Since $\gamma$ is a right angle, $\sin{\gamma} = 1$, and therefore in your example $c = 
\frac{a}{\sin{60°}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed. Who knew it would be so simple :)

Comment: This is shooting an ant with a cannon! Just use the right-angle definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$, as an earlier comment suggested. $a/c = \text{opposite/hypotenuse}=\sin 60^\circ$.

Comment: if you have a nail to pe put on a wall, everything is a hammer :-)

Answer (score 3):

This staple of [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) tends to be taught in schools using the mnemonic "[SOHCAHTOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#Mnemonics)":

- **S**ine of the angle = **O**pposite side length / **H**ypotenuse length.

  - $\sin θ = \frac{Opposite}{Hypotenuse}$
- **C**osine of the angle = **A**djacent side length / **H**ypotenuse length

  - $\cos θ = \frac{Adjacent}{Hypotenuse}$
- **T**angent of the angle = **O**pposite side length / **A**djacent side length

  - $\tan θ = \frac{Opposite}{Adjacent}$

"Adjacent" meaning the side which the given angle joins to the hypotenuse (`a` if you use the angle `30°`), and "Opposite" meaning the side that is not connected to the angle you are using for the calculation (`a` if you use the angle `60°`).

Since both angles are available (even if 60° wasn't stated, you could [calculate it as 180 - 90 - 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_angles_of_a_triangle)), you can choose which of the first two to use, flipping the formula to either of these (both are equivalent):

- **H**ypotenuse length = **O**pposite side length / **S**ine of the angle

  - $Hypotenuse = \frac{Opposite}{\sin θ}$ or in example, $c = \frac{a}{\sin{60°}}$
- **H**ypotenuse length = **A**djacent side length / **C**osine of the angle

  - $Hypotenuse = \frac{Adjacent}{\cos θ}$ or in example, $c = 
    \frac{a}{\cos{30°}}$

Comment: I saw Henrik's comment above saying "in all likelyhood nobody is going to care" about a four-year old question, but this question has over 75,000 views and is on the first page of search results for common searches like "length of hypotenuse from angle", so I think it'd benefit from something that covers the options and jogs the memories of people (like me!) trying to remember this from school...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for that problem the short path is seeing the triangle as the half of an equilateral triangle. Therefore $20$ is the height and you know the relationship between the size and the height:

$$h=s\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \implies s=\frac{2h}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{40}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to 30 60 90 triangles, the short leg equals half of the hypotenuse, and the long leg equals the short times the square root of three.

Comment: You're answering a four-and-half-year old question that has an accepted answer, in all likelyhood nobody is going to care. And while correct and usable in this case, this doesn't answer the general question and as you give no argument it's not even a good answer in this case.